Experiences with Song Meter SM4 versus Frontier Labs Bar-LT?
I love and appreciate the discussions and information available online about Bioacoustics, but there is almost no discussion about comparative value of hardware that is available.
Do people have thoughts on the Bar-lt vs Sm4? Is the difference in terms of what is captured negligible enough to make this not a topic of great interest, or are the Bar-lt units just relatively unknown / unused by the community?
I'd love to see a little more information around on the various units and what metrics an individual newer to the space can use to compare them and make purchasing decisions.
Thank you for your contributions.

AFAIK, this is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum, but I let moderators to decide

I realize, ?you? asked for similar contributions on Wildlabs.net that is a better forum for this kind of survey
